# How can i put two strings with indices en points into Three.js BufferGeometry?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, three.js

I have a database filled with 10,000's objects with all kinds of information about, including their 3D meshes. At the moment I'm trying to make these objects visible in webbrowsers using Three.js.

The information about the objects comes from another party, so I can only use it as I get it. Querying the database I get i.e. the following information:

```
indices: 0;1;2;3;0;2;4;5;2;1;4;2;1;6;7;8;6;9;6;1;9;10;11;12;6;12;11;11;7;6;13;4;1;4;13;14;7;13;1;7;15;13;16;13;15;15;7;17;18;19;7;19;17;7;20;21;22;19;22;21;19;21;17;14;23;4;18;24;25;26;19;25;20;27;28;26;27;22;21;20;28;11;29;7;29;24;7;24;18;7;25;19;18;22;19;26;27;20;22;28;30;21;15;31;32;33;16;32;14;34;35;33;34;13;23;35;36;17;21;30;31;15;17;32;16;15;33;13;16;14;13;34;35;23;14;17;30;31;4;36;37;38;5;37;3;39;40;38;39;2;0;40;41;36;4;23;37;5;4;38;2;5;39;3;2;0;3;40;41;1;0;41;42;1;8;43;44;45;6;44;10;46;47;45;46;12;11;47;29;43;9;42;43;8;9;42;9;1;44;6;8;45;12;6;10;12;46;47;11;10;38;37;36;38;36;39;42;41;40;39;42;40;39;33;44;35;34;36;33;36;34;32;31;33;39;36;33;31;27;33;42;39;43;44;33;27;45;44;46;47;46;27;44;27;46;47;24;29;28;27;30;30;27;31;26;25;27;24;27;25;27;24;47;44;43;39
points: -155.751724243164;106.251846313477;-20000;-127.281639099121;110;-20000;-205.063369750977;77.7817459106445;-20000;-182.281646728516;95.2627868652344;-20000;-233.533477783203;28.4700946807861;-20000;-222.54443359375;55;-20000;-49.4998893737793;77.7817459106445;-20000;-21.0297946929932;-28.4700946807861;-20000;-72.2816314697266;95.2627868652344;-20000;-98.8115386962891;106.251846313477;-20000;-21.0297946929932;28.4700946807861;-20000;-17.2816352844238;1.91109225666786E-10;-20000;-32.0188407897949;55;-20000;-222.54443359375;-55;-20000;-233.533477783203;-28.4700946807861;-20000;-182.281646728516;-95.2627868652344;-20000;-205.063369750977;-77.7817459106445;-20000;-155.751724243164;-106.251846313477;-20000;-32.0188407897949;-55;-20000;-49.4998893737793;-77.7817459106445;-20000;-98.8115386962891;-106.251846313477;-20000;-127.281639099121;-110;-20000;-72.2816314697266;-95.2627868652344;-20000;-237.281631469727;1.90042967473936E-10;-20000;-21.0297946929932;-28.4700946807861;0;-32.0188407897949;-55;0;-49.4998893737793;-77.7817459106445;0;-72.2816314697266;-95.2627868652344;0;-98.8115386962891;-106.251846313477;0;-17.2816352844238;-1.38817108849554E-11;0;-127.281639099121;-110;0;-155.751724243164;-106.251846313477;0;-182.281646728516;-95.2627868652344;0;-205.063369750977;-77.7817459106445;0;-222.54443359375;-55;0;-233.533477783203;-28.4700946807861;0;-237.281631469727;-1.63157647115053E-11;0;-233.533477783203;28.4700946807861;0;-222.54443359375;55;0;-205.063369750977;77.7817459106445;0;-182.281646728516;95.2627868652344;0;-155.751724243164;106.251846313477;0;-127.281639099121;110;0;-98.8115386962891;106.251846313477;0;-72.2816314697266;95.2627868652344;0;-49.4998893737793;77.7817459106445;0;-32.0188407897949;55;0;-21.0297946929932;28.4700946807861;0
```

Now I'm strugling to get this into the BufferGeometry of Three.js. If I follow the example at http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_uint I think I have to use:

```
var triangles = 276;
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var indices = new Uint32Array(triangles * 3);
```

But how can I input my indices-string/array and my points into the Buffer?

EDIT

Using the answer @mlkn gave I fixed my problem. Since my indices en vertices come from a database I adjusted my string in php (server-side) so the client-side does not need to do the loops. My code now looks like this:

```
var vertices = new Float32Array([-155.751724243164,106.251846313477,-20000,...]);
var indices = new Uint16Array([0,1,2,3,0,2,4,5,2,...]);

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
geometry.setIndex( new THREE.BufferAttribute( indices, 1 ) );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffbb0f});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add(mesh);
```

...and it works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to convert strings into typed arrays. Assuming data is correct:

```
var i, length;
var tmp = indicesData.split(';');
var indices = new Uint16Array(tmp.length);
for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    indices[i] = parseInt(tmp[i]);
}

tmp = verticesData.split(';');
var vertices = new Float32Array(tmp.length);
for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    vertices[i] = parseFloat(tmp[i]);
}
```

After that [create geometry/material](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry), create mesh and add it to scene:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
geometry.setIndex( new THREE.BufferAttribute( indices, 1 ) );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffbb0f});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add(mesh);
```

When you get new data you could add new meshes or update buffers of existing geometries. If you are not sure that data is proper sized and no indices are out of range of vertices buffer check it to avoid runtime error.

Also, there is [an article about indexed drawing](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial10/tutorial10.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great! Using a sql-query to get the information from my database into the script it works. My next step will be to put several 10,000's of this geometries into the buffer.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you want to load data in same buffer take a look at function gl.bufferSubData. It allows you to update buffer partially.